# C# Streamreader problems

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader

I'm building a program that has you input a number and remembers it when you re-open the program. It uses a text file to save the number in. I'm using streamreader to read the text file to get the number you entered last, but it always throws an exception. Where should I put the text file or change my code so it can read and edit the text? Here is my code:

```
namespace Cookie_Clicker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tb_TextBox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("cookies.txt"))
                {
                    int data = Convert.ToInt16(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    tb.Text = Convert.ToString(data + 1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your cookie text file is missing!");
            }
        }

        private void reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Where is the code that saves the file?

Comment: try this catch block -> `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToSTring(); }`

Comment: Sorry, the text file is in the folder VisualStudio\Projects\CookieClicker

Comment: you didn't write anything to a file. (at least in this code)

Comment: Thanks @SudhakarTillapudi, I realized that the text file was in the "release" folder not the "debug"!

Comment: Your edit to remove the fact that it always showed the message box is bad, makes the question harder to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every time it says "Your cookie text file is missing!"

**Problem 1:** You are not specifying proper path of your input file.

**Solution 1:** You need to get the Currentpath of your application from where it is running and then combine it with the filename using `Path.Combine()` method.

Try This:

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"cookies.txt");
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    int data = Convert.ToInt16(sr.ReadToEnd());
    tb.Text = Convert.ToString(data + 1);
}
```

**Suggestion :** You need to always display the Error message in Catch block to identify the problem.

You can call `ToString()` on  Exception object to get the complete exception info.

```
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToSTring(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> Where should I put the text file...?

You haven't specified a path to cookies.txt so the program will look for it in the same directory where it's running. If you change `cookies.txt` to include a path, for example `C:\dev\cookies.txt`, then you can store the file wherever you like.

That will allow you to get past the file not found error and address any other problems you have in there.